# Using socket.io with RESTful API, routed by Ingress

Tags: rest, kubernetes, socket.io, nginx-ingress

I have a chat app that uses socket.io. I also have a database in the same service that saves chat history. The RESTful API either saves chats or gets the chat history. The problem is, whenever i call the RESTful API from client side, it always times out before the server sends back a response, seems like it's stuck (504 error).
The error also includes something like ingress so I'm guessing something's wrong with the Ingress config?

The server file:

```js
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import { json } from 'body-parser';
import { addUser, getUser, generateMessage } from '@tlbooktrading/common';

// below are the REST API routes used by app as middleware
import { indexChatRouter } from './routes';
import { addChatRouter } from './routes/add';

const app = express();
app.set('trust proxy', true);
app.use(json());
app.use(indexChatRouter);
app.use(addChatRouter);

const server = createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server);
const nsp = io.of('/chat');

let socketid: string;

const connectMongo = async () => {
    if (!process.env.MONGO_URI) {
        throw new Error('MONGO_URI must be defined');
    }
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
        console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

connectMongo();

nsp.on('connection', (socket) => {
    ...
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on 3000!`);
});
```

The ingress file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: ingress-service
    annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
        nginx.org/websocket-services: 'chat-srv'
spec:
    rules:
        - host: booktrading.dev
          http:
              paths:
                  // REST endpoints
                  - path: /api/chats/?(.*)
                    pathType: Prefix
                    backend:
                        service:
                            name: chat-srv
                            port:
                                number: 3000
                  // Namespace for socket.io
                  - path: /chat/?(.*)
                    pathType: Prefix
                    backend:
                        service:
                            name: chat-srv
                            port:
                                number: 3000
                  - path: /socket.io/.*
                    pathType: Prefix
                    backend:
                        service:
                            name: chat-srv
                            port:
                                number: 3000
                  - path: /?(.*)
                    pathType: Prefix
                    backend:
                        service:
                            name: client-srv
                            port:
                                number: 3000
```

Deployment and Service file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: chat-depl
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: chat
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: chat
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: chat
                  image: tommyling79/book-trading-chat
                  env:
                      - name: MONGO_URI
                        value: mongodb://chat-mongo-srv:27017/chat
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: chat-srv
spec:
    selector:
        app: chat
    ports:
        - name: chat
          protocol: TCP
          port: 3000
          targetPort: 3000
```

Comment: Hello. `The error also includes something like ingress`. Would you be able to share that error with us?

Comment: @PaulEvans it throws back a prettified html file with `504 Gateway Time-out` and `nginx` in the body tag

Comment: Does your docker image actually expose your app when not putting it behind kubenetes? Does running it using only docker commands works? Try debugging your network stack by using curl commands on the pod ip, then service ip, and then your ingress.